# How can I insert a extra HTML tag?

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I have this bit of code, but I would like to enable `<br />` or any other TAG before `username`.

```
$liked = mysql_num_rows($likequery) > 0 ? $likers . " <b>likes</b> this." : "";
```

I want to enable a HTML tag before the `$likers` variable to allow margin dropping it with the other part of it I have.

Example to be desired (invalid I know):

```
$liked = mysql_num_rows($likequery) > 0 ? . "HTML CODE HERE" . $likers . " <b>likes</b> this." : "";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just leave the `.` after the `?` out and you are done:

```
$liked = mysql_num_rows($likequery) > 0 ? "HTML CODE HERE" . $likers . " <b>likes</b> this." : "";
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you all so much. I suppose I was in the right direction. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in front of your string.

```
$liked = "HTML CODE HERE" . (mysql_num_rows($likequery) > 0 ? $likers . " <b>likes</b> this." : "");
```

EDIT:

Ah well ok. I reread your question and i think this is not what you wanted: If you really only want to prepend the tags in this single condition your code should look like this:

```
$liked = mysql_num_rows($likequery) > 0 ? "HTML CODE HERE" . $likers . " <b>likes</b> this." : "";
```